# app doesnt stay within facebook on firefox and chrome

Tags: facebook, cross-browser, facebook-canvas

I'm creating a facebook app and on Internet Explorer 9 it works fine. But on Firefox and Chrome when I goto the canvas page it redirects away from facebook and to my site.

Think it's something to do with how I'm redirecting people from `index.php` to `home.php`

Is there anything in this that would cause the problem :

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='home.php'</script>");
```

Comment: thanks but same thing happens, instead of going to http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/home.php it goes to mysite.com/myapp/home.php :(

Comment: http://apps.facebook.com/hotness-battle/

Comment: try taking off the 'top.' part and just use location.href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/home.php'</script>");
```

or:

```
echo("<script>location.href='home.php'</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the Bookmark URL you have in application settings? It should be http://apps.facebook.com/appname. I had the same issue when I mistakenly had the canvas URL in the bookmark url field.